# How to make a regex match two parameters and group them

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

```
function toCamelCase(str){

 str.replace(/_(.)/g, function(match, group1) {
        return group1.toUpperCase();
    });

}
```

I am trying to write code for changing a string to CamelCase. The string in the test case have both an underscore delimiter and dash delimiter. So currently, that code above works for underscore but not dash. How do I add a dash to the expression in such a way that it tells it to match either a dash or underscore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to alternate between single characters, the optimal way to express that is to use a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html):

```js
function toCamelCase(str){
 return str.replace(/[_-](.)/g, function(match, group1) {
        return group1.toUpperCase();
    });
}

var s = "hi-there, go_to camel-case"
alert(toCamelCase(s))
```

Side note: You need to be careful when placing a dash in a character class since it can also be used as a range indicator (as in `[a-z]`). But if the dash is at the start or end of the character class (as in our regex), it does match a literal dash.

Comment: just tried this, it didn't pass the testcase. any other suggestion?

Comment: What's your test case?

Comment: 1. Test.assertEquals(toCamelCase(''), '', "An empty string was provided but not returned")
2. Test.assertEquals(toCamelCase("the_stealth_warrior"), "theStealthWarrior", "toCamelCase('the_stealth_warrior') did not return correct value")
3. Test.assertEquals(toCamelCase("The-Stealth-Warrior"), "TheStealthWarrior", "toCamelCase('The-Stealth-Warrior') did not return correct value")
4. Test.assertEquals(toCamelCase("A-B-C"), "ABC", "toCamelCase('A-B-C') did not return correct value")

Comment: Oh yes, your function was faulty - it didn't return anything. See my updated answer with code snippet

Comment: That's true, there was no return statement, works now.

Comment: This is the best answer. You *could* use a non-capturing group, `/(?:_|-)(.)/`, which basically says "I'm using this for regex grouping only, don't return me as `group1`", but with just 2 characters this is simpler and cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use pipe between the two of your possible characters like this, here `(_|-)` means either **underscore** or **dash** character.

```
function toCamelCase(str){

 str.replace(/(?:_|-)(.)/g, function(match, group1) {
        return group1.toUpperCase();
    });

}
```

Comment: That's not going to work since now the dash or underscore will be captured in group 1.

Comment: Yeah that's my bad, in that case non-capturing will work. see my edit